# Why can't I save new points created in QField?

Tags: qgis, qfield

We are using QField 0.7.5 that seems a really great project to bring QGis on a mobile device.

- I prepared a QGis 2016 project : orthophoto + 1 polygon layer (casdatre) + 1 point layer to input data.
- I transferred the project and the data to a Galaxy Tab A (Android 5.0.2).
  I open the project with QField and everything displays fine, I can move and query the data, really great.

But when I create a point, I can't save the new point (save don’t save the new point).

Do you have any idea what’s wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are potentially two things that could trigger this behavior.

1. The project might be located on an external SD card. Android prevents apps from writing to external SD cards except for an app specific folder. If you save the project on an external SD card, put your data into the folder

```
/Android/data/ch.opengis.qfield/files
```

See also: [Documentation](http://www.qfield.org/docs/project-management/android-data-structure.html#external-sd-card), [Issue report](https://github.com/opengisch/QField/issues/32)

*The second reason no longer applies and is here for reference only*

2. The layer in which you digitize is not in the same CRS as the project itself. This is [mentioned in the documentation](http://www.qfield.org/docs/project-management/index.html#coordinate-reference-systems). [It is also reported as a bug](https://github.com/opengisch/QField/issues/58) in the current version that newly digitized geometries are not reprojected.
   *Update: This issue is fixed in QField >= 0.8*

Comment: That's it! If all layers and the QGis project share the same SRC, the new points record fine

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the quick answer.
The pb was that my QGis project and the vector layers where in Lambert93 (SRC 2154).
I used the QGis extension QTiles to transform the raster orthophoto to the .mbtiles format, but the result file was in SCR 3857...

I put everything in SCR 3857 and that rocks !

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the 'cable layer action' set to 'offline editing'

(Go to the QField tab in the layer properties)

For some reason the default 'cloud layer action' is set to 'offline editing' and the default 'cable layer action' is set to 'copy' - therefore the default 'cable layer action' version of the project (copied to QField via cable and not on through the clouds) does not allow editing until you set it to 'offline editing'.

At least for my version of QField/QGIS anyway...

Also, a few Python errors come up when you change the layer action, not sure what they mean but it doesn't affect the end goal here.

Comment: I can't find this option anywhere.  Got any pics you could post?