# How to properly store QGIS Qfield folders on an Android SD Card?

Tags: qgis, android, qfield, mobile-gis

I am using QField on an Android 7 tablet with SD Card. It works very well when I store my QField folders in the onboard storage in tablet/Android/Data/ch.opengis.qfield/files but if I store it in SDCard/Android/Data/ch.opengis.qfield/files QField cannot 'see' it to open it. Ideally I would like to move my QField data to the SD Card to save onboard storage space. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: /Android/data/ch.opengis.qfield/files needs read and write access https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/209361/why-cant-i-save-new-points-created-in-qfield/209373

Comment: I have saved it in that folder and all the app permissions have been approved. I have no other way to grant read and write access to it.